# Convert this datetime from SQL Server to Snowflake

Tags: date, datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this piece of code that works in SQL server. I'm having trouble getting it to run in snowflake. 'Datetime' is filetype DateTime in snowflake, but in SQL, it's just a date MM-DD-YYYY, so there is the 6:00 added to turn it into a datetime.

I want the end result to be a date.

Below is SQL Server:

```
CONVERT(DATE, TEMP.DATETIME - ISNULL((
                SELECT CAST(MIN(s_first.FromTimeOfDay) AS DATETIME)
                FROM Shift s_first
                WHERE s_first.FromDay = s.FromDay
                    AND s_first.ShiftCalendarID = s.ShiftCalendarID
                ), CAST('6:00' AS DATETIME))) AS ProductionDate
```

Here is what I have in Snowflake:

```
to_date(TEMP.DATETIME) - ifnull(to_date((
                SELECT MIN(s_first.FromTimeOfDay)
                FROM Shift s_first
                WHERE s_first.FromDay = s.FromDay
                    AND s_first.ShiftCalendarID = s.ShiftCalendarID
                ), (
                SELECT to_date('1900-01-01 06:00:00.000')
                ))) AS ProductionDate
```

It's not liking the filetype. I get a filetype error:

> invalid type [TO_DATE((SELECT MIN(S_FIRST.FROMTIMEOFDAY) AS "MIN(S_FIRST.FROMTIMEOFDAY)" FROM SHIFT AS S_FIRST WHERE (S_FIRST.FROMDAY = CORRELATION(S.FROMDAY)) AND (S_FIRST.SHIFTCALENDARID = CORRELATION(S.SHIFTCALENDARID))), (SELECT TO_DATE('1900-01-01 06:00:00.000') AS "TO_DATE('1900-01-01 06:00:00.000')" FROM (VALUES (null)) DUAL))] for parameter 'TO_DATE'

Update::

This is the original SQL that i'm trying to write in snowflake.

```
SELECT
    e.Name AS ProductionUnit,
    temp.DateTime AS DateTime,
    s.Reference AS Shift,
    CONVERT(TIME, temp.DateTime) AS Time,
    CONVERT(DATE, temp.DateTime - ISNULL((SELECT CAST(MIN(s_first.FromTimeOfDay) AS DateTime) FROM Shift s_first WHERE s_first.FromDay = s.FromDay AND s_first.ShiftCalendarID = s.ShiftCalendarID), CAST('6:00' AS DateTime))) AS ProductionDate,
    temp.ScrapReason AS ScrapReason,
    temp.Quantity AS ScrapQuantity,
    'Manually Registered' AS RegistrationType
FROM (SELECT
        CAST(SUM(sreg.ScrapQuantity) AS int) AS Quantity,
        sreas.Name As ScrapReason,
        DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 * (DATEPART(MINUTE, sreg.ScrapTime) / 30), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, sreg.ScrapTime), 0)) AS DateTime,
        srer.EquipmentID AS EquipmentID
    FROM qms.ScrapRegistration sreg WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN qms.ScrapReason sreas WITH (NOLOCK) ON sreas.ID = sreg.ScrapReasonID
    INNER JOIN WorkRequest wr WITH (NOLOCK) ON wr.ID = sreg.WorkRequestID
    INNER JOIN SegmentRequirementEquipmentRequirement srer WITH (NOLOCK) ON srer.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 * (DATEPART(MINUTE, sreg.ScrapTime) / 30), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, sreg.ScrapTime), 0)), srer.EquipmentID, sreas.Name) temp
INNER JOIN Equipment e WITH (NOLOCK) ON e.ID = temp.EquipmentID
INNER JOIN ShiftCalendar sc WITH (NOLOCK) ON sc.ID = dbo.cfn_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID(e.ID, temp.DateTime)
INNER JOIN Shift s WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.ID = dbo.cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime(temp.DateTime, sc.ID)
UNION
SELECT
    e.Name AS ProductionUnit,
    temp.DateTime AS DateTime,
    s.Reference AS Shift,
    CONVERT(TIME, temp.DateTime) AS Time,
    CONVERT(DATE, temp.DateTime - ISNULL((SELECT CAST(MIN(s_first.FromTimeOfDay) AS DateTime) FROM Shift s_first WHERE s_first.FromDay = s.FromDay AND s_first.ShiftCalendarID = s.ShiftCalendarID), CAST('6:00' AS DateTime))) AS ProductionDate,
    temp.ScrapReason AS ScrapReason,
    temp.Quantity AS ScrapQuantity,
    'Auto Registered' AS RegistrationType
FROM (SELECT
        SUM(ISNULL(asr.ScrapQuantity, 0)) AS Quantity,
        sreas.Name As ScrapReason,
        DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 * (DATEPART(MINUTE, asr.ScrapTime) / 30), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, asr.ScrapTime), 0)) AS DateTime,
        srer.EquipmentID AS EquipmentID
    FROM proj.AutoScrapRegistration asr WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN qms.ScrapReason sreas WITH (NOLOCK) ON sreas.ID = asr.ScrapReasonID
    INNER JOIN WorkRequest wr WITH (NOLOCK) ON wr.ID = asr.WorkRequestID
    INNER JOIN SegmentRequirementEquipmentRequirement srer WITH (NOLOCK) ON srer.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 * (DATEPART(MINUTE, asr.ScrapTime) / 30), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, asr.ScrapTime), 0)), srer.EquipmentID, sreas.Name) temp
INNER JOIN Equipment e WITH (NOLOCK) ON e.ID = temp.EquipmentID
INNER JOIN ShiftCalendar sc WITH (NOLOCK) ON sc.ID = dbo.cfn_GetEquipmentShiftCalendarID(temp.EquipmentID, temp.DateTime)
INNER JOIN Shift s WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.ID = dbo.cfn_GetShiftIDFromDateTime(temp.DateTime, sc.ID)
```

Comment: No point tagging SQL Server when you want your solution in Snowflake.

Answer (score 2):

So the first step is to make up some T-SQL data that to help understand hwo the old can ran.

So taking the inner most step on the original sql:

```
with Shift as (
    select * from (values 
        (1, '2020-11-03', '06:30' )
    ) as t(ShiftCalendarID, fromday, FromTimeOfDay)
)
 SELECT CAST(MIN(s_first.FromTimeOfDay) AS DATETIME) as sub
                FROM Shift s_first;
```

we get:

| sub |
| --- |
| 1900-01-01 06:30:00.000 |

so we can then weave `temp` and `s` together into this CTE data:

```
with Shift as (
    select * from (
        values 
        (1, '2020-11-03', '06:30' )
    ) as t(ShiftCalendarID, fromday, FromTimeOfDay)
), temp as (
    select
        t.ShiftCalendarID, 
        t.FromDay, 
        CAST(t.date_time AS DATETIME) as date_time
    from (
        values
        (1, '2020-11-03', '2020-11-03 07:41:12' ),
        (1, '2020-11-03', '2020-11-03 05:41:12' )
    ) as t(ShiftCalendarID, FromDay, date_time )
)
```

and run your existing sql:

```
select t.*
    ,CONVERT(DATE, t.date_time - ISNULL((
                SELECT CAST(MIN(s_first.FromTimeOfDay) AS DATETIME)
                FROM Shift s_first
                WHERE s_first.FromDay = t.FromDay
                    AND s_first.ShiftCalendarID = t.ShiftCalendarID
                ), CAST('6:00' AS DATETIME))) AS ProductionDate
from temp as t;
```

which gives:

| ShiftCalendarID | FromDay | date_time | ProductionDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-11-03 | 2020-11-03 07:41:12.000 | 2020-11-03 |
| 1 | 2020-11-03 | 2020-11-03 05:41:12.000 | 2020-11-02 |

there is a subtraction of a time component from a datetime, if the min is not present a default of 6am is used.

And this code looks very much like it's a correlated subquery, so that will have it's own issues, but using the above fake data in snowflake:

so the data CTE's:

```
with Shift as (
    select * from values 
        (1, '2020-11-03', '06:30' )
     t(ShiftCalendarID, fromday, FromTimeOfDay)
), temp as (
    select
        t.ShiftCalendarID, 
        t.FromDay, 
        t.date_time::timestamp as date_time
    from values
        (1, '2020-11-03', '2020-11-03 07:41:12' ),
        (1, '2020-11-03', '2020-11-03 05:41:12' ),
        (2, '2020-11-03', '2020-11-03 05:41:12' )
     t(ShiftCalendarID, FromDay, date_time )
)
```

and an extra help CTE to resolve the correlated subquery:

```
, min_times as (
    select 
        ShiftCalendarID, 
        fromday,
        MIN(FromTimeOfDay) as FromTimeOfDay
    from Shift
    group by 1,2
)
```

and then this expanded SQL to see all the steps:

```
select t.*
    ,nvl(mt.FromTimeOfDay::time, '06:00'::time) as sub_time
    ,dateadd('hour', -hour(sub_time), t.date_time) as da1
    ,dateadd('minute', -minute(sub_time), da1) as da2
    ,da2::date as ProductionDate
from temp as t
left join min_times as mt
    on t.ShiftCalendarID = mt.ShiftCalendarID
        and t.FromDay = mt.FromDay
```

gives:

| SHIFTCALENDARID | FROMDAY | DATE_TIME | SUB_TIME | DA1 | DA2 | PRODUCTIONDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-11-03 | 2020-11-03 07:41:12.000 | 06:30:00 | 2020-11-03 01:41:12.000 | 2020-11-03 01:11:12.000 | 2020-11-03 |
| 1 | 2020-11-03 | 2020-11-03 05:41:12.000 | 06:30:00 | 2020-11-02 23:41:12.000 | 2020-11-02 23:11:12.000 | 2020-11-02 |
| 2 | 2020-11-03 | 2020-11-03 05:41:12.000 | 06:00:00 | 2020-11-02 23:41:12.000 | 2020-11-02 23:41:12.000 | 2020-11-02 |

so that can then be compacted (perhaps too far)..

```
select t.*
    ,dateadd('minute', -minute(nvl(mt.FromTimeOfDay::time, '06:00'::time)), dateadd('hour', -hour(nvl(mt.FromTimeOfDay::time, '06:00'::time)), t.date_time))::date as ProductionDate
from temp as t
left join min_times as mt
    on t.ShiftCalendarID = mt.ShiftCalendarID
        and t.FromDay = mt.FromDay
```

less compacted:

```
select ShiftCalendarID, FROMDAY, ProductionDate
from (
    select t.ShiftCalendarID
        ,t.FROMDAY
        ,nvl(mt.FromTimeOfDay::time, '06:00'::time) as sub_time
        ,dateadd('hour', -hour(sub_time), t.date_time) as da1
        ,dateadd('minute', -minute(sub_time), da1) as da2
        ,da2::date as ProductionDate
    from temp as t
    left join min_times as mt
        on t.ShiftCalendarID = mt.ShiftCalendarID
            and t.FromDay = mt.FromDay
)
```

| SHIFTCALENDARID | FROMDAY | PRODUCTIONDATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-11-03 | 2020-11-03 |
| 1 | 2020-11-03 | 2020-11-02 |
| 2 | 2020-11-03 | 2020-11-02 |

Comment: thank you for this, maybe i'm overthinking this, but how would i put this in a single line in the column of a select statement?

Comment: `,dateadd('minute', -minute(nvl(mt.FromTimeOfDay::time, '06:00'::time)), dateadd('hour', -hour(nvl(mt.FromTimeOfDay::time, '06:00'::time)), t.date_time))::date as ProductionDate` is a single line

Comment: It's still not executing as i'd expect. I update the question with the entire SQL script that i'm trying to convert to Snowflake. I'm fairly new to snowflake syntax which is where i'm having issues. The temp table is a table that's joined in the query. if you look at it you'll see what i mean. I just cant seem to piece this together @Simeon Pilgrim

Comment: any thoughts or ideas

Comment: my honest thought is "you are getting paid to convert some SQL" and yet seem to be failing at the task of understanding the old code, and understanding the gap in the new code, or breaking your new task down into smaller chunks of confirmable work. Thus pasting your whole SQL and asking me to do your job for you is like asking for free money, which is offensive, is what I think.

Comment: Which is to say, I am happy to help teach you the finer points of SQL, how to be good developer,  or how to use Snowflake well. But I am not interested in doing your job.

Comment: i understand. i'm actually a business analyst. this is beyond the scope of my job, the other developer couldn't/wouldn't do it and it would help me if these views were moved to snowflake since i can compare it against other data. apologies. i'll figure this out. 

I'm fairly comfortable writing views in snowflake, but I've never done something like this and figured it was a good challenge. perhaps too good. i appreciate your help